# On the back of the package or at the back of package?

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english

Is this sticker:

> "On the back of the package" **or**
>
> "At the back of package"

I am confused.

[image]

I do not know the use of ***on*** or ***at***. Waiting for somebody's reply.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you're trying to say.

"On" usually means "connected to". So if you say something is "on the back of the package", it sounds like there is something connected to outside of the package on its back side (for example, a sticky note).

"At" usually means "in a specific place". So if you say something is "at the back of the package", it sounds like there is something inside the package, located in the area that is in the back.

For example:

- I sat *at* the back of the bus.
- There was a giant bug *on* the back of her chair.
- He stood *at* the back of the crowd.
- They wrote *on* the back of the paper.

Comment: i want to put the sentences' what's on/at the back ' in my products manual like the picture shows

Comment: @WelcomeOhmybaby accept the edit.

Comment: @WelcomeOhmybaby What specifically do you want to say? If you're more specific, I can offer a more direct answer. What kind of product? What is on/at the back? Is it something inside the package? Something outside the package?

Comment: "what's on/at the back" is a sentence in my product instruction manual. Just to contract people to see the words of the back of page

Comment: The post-it note in your picture would be **on** the back of the package (if that is what you are referring to).

Comment: I see, so this is for something written *on* the back of your product manual? (And that's also your answer, if I understand you correctly)